# I want to add entry boxes in the frame f1b, which in turn is placed on a canvas c1 (sorry not able to embed image under the postb

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I want to add entry boxes in the frame f1b, which in turn is places on a canvas c1. When I add entries to frame f1b directly, frame is not visible. Or should I add them to canvas using create_window? Could someone please help me here..

```
  from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()



f1 = Frame(root,bg="cyan")
f1.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=YES)  #now frame f1 occupies full root window

f1a = Frame(f1,bg="gold",height=100,width=100)
f1a.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=10)

#for drawing rectangles on canvas 
c1 = Canvas(f1,height=400,width=800,bg="snow")




c1.create_rectangle(50,50,750,100)
c1.create_rectangle(50,130,750,200)
c1.create_rectangle(50,220,750,300)
c1.create_text(100,70,text="Sensor1",font=40)
c1.create_text(100,170,text="Sensor2",font=40)
c1.create_text(100,260,text="Sensor3",font=40)
c1.grid(row=3,column=3)


#frame on canvas
f1b=Frame(c1,width=150,height=300,bd=3,highlightcolor="black",highlightthickness=1,highlightbackground="black",relief=RAISED)
c1.create_window(420,160,window=f1b)






c1.update()
root.mainloop()
```

! [] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBPEu.png)

I tried to add entry using the following code:

e1 = Entry(f1b,width=10)

e1.grid(row=3,column=4,padx=10,pady=10)

Update:
![image updated][https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ44D.png]

Comment: When I run your code -- including the code to create the entry widget -- the entry widget shows up for me.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. But then I could not see the frame. That was the issue. But I fixed the issue by creating entries on to canvas.

Comment: When I put the frames, some part of the canvas rectangles are not seen right. Could you please tell me how I can make them as well visible? In this way I could arrange the horizontal elements in Canvas rectangles and vertical elements in Frames.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "some part... are not seen right". With the posted code, you're intentionally putting the entry widgets and frame on top of the other canvas items, so of course parts of the rectangles won't be seen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir...Can I still make the border of the canvas rectangle visible through the frame? Like in the picture I have updated above? If I could do it, then I could make a canvas rectangle correspond to a single item alone...

Comment: _"Can I still make the border of the canvas rectangle visible through the frame? "_ - no. widgets embedded in the canvas will always be on top of other canvas objects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir..I have been trying a lot whether I could find a solution to that...Without using canvas rectangle, I couldn't draw a rectangle for the horizontal placement of widgets. I would want to highlight vertical elements somehow...that is how ended up having a frame to enclose the vertical entries...could you have a suggestion for me here from your experience? to highlight vertical elements in such a scenario to make it appealing to the user? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Sorry to bother you...Shall I ask you one more doubt...Can I create widgets only via create_window on canvas? I have placed frames on canvas...but not to place other widgets on frame, I have used create window method of canvas again..Is that the right method sir?